# Get data from a table with JQuery on mouse click

Tags: jquery

I got a page where there is a table generated using CodeIgniter's table class.
Now is it possible to get the contents of a `<td>` tag by clicking on it using JQuery.
For example
My Table is something like this:

```
<table>
<th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th>
<tr><td>25</td><td>Jack</td><td>15</td></tr>
<tr><td>20</td><td>Jill</td><td>16</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I get the contents (text) inside the  tag when it is clicked?

Comment: I do not understand what the question is

Comment: The question was how can I get the contents (text) inside the <td> tag when i click on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('table td').click(function() { 
    var text = $(this).text(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$("table td").click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Or:

```
$("table td").click(function(){
    alert(this.innerText);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akcSY/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this...

The JS:

```
$('table td').click(function() {
var mvalue = $(this).text(); /*you can store in in a variable and use it for something else later*/
alert(mvalue); /*this provides a popup on top of the screen*/
console.log(mvalue); /*this shows you the value in your web console in case you are debugging*/
});
```

View my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/d6qys/2/) for a demo

Answer (score 1):

I would prefere using a link, its more userfriendly:

html:

```
...
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">25</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Jack</a></td>
    <td><a href="#"15</a></td>
</tr>
...
```

javascript:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).text(); 
});
```